# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role in rest webservice

Tags: rest, jpa, ejb

I tried this code

```
  @GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public Customer getMsg() {
    Customer cus =  em.find(Customer.class,1);
    return cus;
}
```

Customer class has one to many relationship with address entity.
but when i tried to cal ws from my ajax client its give me this error ? how to solve this.
application runs on jboss-eap-6.2 to and that class is stateless bean.

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.test.Customer.addresslist, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the fetchType to EAGER or you need to retrieve the address while the entity is still attached which means you need to retrieve it in that method you have before you return.  If you are using JPA 2.1 then you can probably use an entity graph

Comment: when i'm using eager method its give me  javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception.
I dnt want address of custmers. Only i want retrieve customer entity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider apply **@XmlTransient** in Address field, the error that are you getting is because the state fo the entity is not managed as your are outside the transaction as your property is LAZY when Marshall use the accessor methods, it try to load address and as your are outside the transaction the error happends, so consider and @XmlTransient to avoid the marshall try to use Address.

```
public class Customer

 @XmlTransient
 public Address addresslist
```

Apply that it your are using Jaxb, if not consider search something similar to avoid marshall some fields in your entity.